USB stick damaged during a blackout
I was copying some files to a USB stick, the process would have taken 1 hour or so but a few minutes later after the process started I had a blackout, and when the power got restored I could not mount the main partition of the USB stick
The following dmesg dumps are several attempts I made to try and delete the partition and the partition table of the device using GParted:
The partition would not open in Windows and the explorer would just freeze trying to open it, I booted into Linux just to see the same problem happening, so it was not an OS issue. At Linux when I saw the dmesg it looks like the device is having read errors and ultimately disconnects/powers off from the OS
The following dmesg dump is me trying to delete the partition or (and) partition table of the device
NOTE: The stick was already empty before the copy, so there is no data that I want to recover: I'm interested in recovering the device and having functioning again to continue the work I was doing
I plug in the device
[   83.256016] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[   83.473526] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 0.01
[   83.473534] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   83.473536] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[   83.473539] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Kingston
[   83.473541] usb 1-1.3.2: SerialNumber: E0D55EA57404F491A9126BD5
[   83.481588] usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[   83.481885] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0
[   84.509070] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[   84.509504] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[   84.510243] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 60437492 512-byte logical blocks: (30.9 GB/28.8 GiB)
[   84.511011] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[   84.511018] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[   84.511739] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[   84.541031]  sdd: sdd1
[   84.543857] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk

Everything looks normal so I attempt to delete the partition using GParted
[  181.500005] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  186.864010] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  202.480003] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  202.768005] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  208.112017] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  223.728000] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  224.015993] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  234.763994] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 7, error -110
[  234.943994] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[  245.771992] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 7, error -110
[  245.772669] usb 1-1.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
[  245.796058] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
[  245.796067] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, lost async page write
[  245.796070] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 1, lost async page write
[  245.796091] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 2, lost async page write
[  245.796093] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 3, lost async page write
[  245.796095] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 4, lost async page write
[  245.796097] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 5, lost async page write
[  245.796100] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 6, lost async page write
[  245.796102] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 7, lost async page write
[  245.796105] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 8, lost async page write
[  245.796125] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60437456 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
[  245.796127] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 15109364, lost async page write
[  245.796152] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  245.796193] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2048 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[  246.019997] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[  251.375994] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  266.991992] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  267.279999] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[  272.623994] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  288.239989] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  288.348173] usb 1-1.3-port2: attempt power cycle
[  289.052009] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[  299.788006] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 10, error -110
[  299.971996] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using ehci-pci
[  310.796004] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 11, error -110
[  310.796170] usb 1-1.3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

[  376.152549] buffer_io_error: 9 callbacks suppressed
[  376.152552] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[  376.152560] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 1, async page read
[  378.386002] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, async page read
[  378.386012] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 1, async page read

I unplug the device and then reconnected it but to wipe and create a new partition table. When I opened GParted, the old partition was already gone: there were no partitions visible

[  579.639995] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  579.857600] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 0.01
[  579.857608] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  579.857611] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[  579.857613] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Kingston
[  579.857616] usb 1-1.3.2: SerialNumber: E0D55EA57404F491A9126BD5
[  579.865709] usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  579.865880] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0
[  580.893030] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  580.893468] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  580.894479] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 60437492 512-byte logical blocks: (30.9 GB/28.8 GiB)
[  580.895205] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  580.895210] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[  580.895942] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  580.923719] GPT:partition_entry_array_crc32 values don't match: 0xab54d286 != 0x2ef1fcff
[  580.923725] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[  580.923732]  sdd:
[  580.926566] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  600.947714] GPT:partition_entry_array_crc32 values don't match: 0xab54d286 != 0x2ef1fcff
[  600.947722] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[  600.947740]  sdd:
[  601.146492] GPT:partition_entry_array_crc32 values don't match: 0xab54d286 != 0x2ef1fcff
[  601.146499] GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors.
[  601.146509]  sdd:
[  650.491984] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  655.856008] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  671.475979] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  671.767994] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  677.103987] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  692.719998] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  693.007984] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  703.755996] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 12, error -110
[  703.935990] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
[  714.764000] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 12, error -110
[  714.764394] usb 1-1.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 12
[  714.783976] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[  714.783985] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, lost async page write
[  714.783987] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 1, lost async page write
[  714.783994] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 2, lost async page write
[  714.783996] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 3, lost async page write
[  714.783998] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 4, lost async page write
[  714.783999] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 5, lost async page write
[  714.784000] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 6, lost async page write
[  714.784001] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 7, lost async page write
[  714.784003] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 8, lost async page write
[  714.784004] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 9, lost async page write
[  714.784045] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 240 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[  714.784081] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[  714.784145] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 488 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 35 prio class 0
[  714.784208] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 628 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 59 prio class 0
[  714.784285] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 864 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 40 prio class 0
[  714.784316] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 131072 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[  714.784379] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60435968 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[  714.784420] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60436208 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
[  714.784530] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60436244 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[  714.984025] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[  720.371979] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  720.371979] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  735.988017] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  736.276008] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
[  741.615991] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  757.231991] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[  757.340149] usb 1-1.3-port2: attempt power cycle
[  758.043978] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using ehci-pci
[  768.779997] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 15, error -110
[  768.960011] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
[  779.788005] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 16, error -110
[  779.788153] usb 1-1.3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

Reconnected the device again. The last time I didn't read the following "GPT: Use GNU Parted to correct GPT errors", so after a quick Google search about it I expected to run the parted command to seee what would happen, but this time that message did not appear. I tried running GParted again, the same thing happens
[ 1207.860005] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1208.081635] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0951, idProduct=1666, bcdDevice= 0.01
[ 1208.081643] usb 1-1.3.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 1208.081647] usb 1-1.3.2: Product: DataTraveler 3.0
[ 1208.081649] usb 1-1.3.2: Manufacturer: Kingston
[ 1208.081651] usb 1-1.3.2: SerialNumber: E0D55EA57404F491A9126BD5
[ 1208.089733] usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 1208.089910] scsi host5: usb-storage 1-1.3.2:1.0
[ 1209.116917] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0      PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[ 1209.117310] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 1209.118135] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] 60437492 512-byte logical blocks: (30.9 GB/28.8 GiB)
[ 1209.118846] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[ 1209.118853] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 4f 00 00 00
[ 1209.119600] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 1209.138720] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 1395.967973] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1401.327974] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1416.947988] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1417.239982] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1422.575970] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1438.191971] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1438.479966] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1449.231982] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 17, error -110
[ 1449.411984] usb 1-1.3.2: reset high-speed USB device number 17 using ehci-pci
[ 1460.235984] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 17, error -110
[ 1460.236456] usb 1-1.3.2: USB disconnect, device number 17
[ 1460.256002] print_req_error: 7 callbacks suppressed
[ 1460.256006] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[ 1460.256018] buffer_io_error: 510 callbacks suppressed
[ 1460.256020] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 0, lost async page write
[ 1460.256038] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 1, lost async page write
[ 1460.256057] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 2, lost async page write
[ 1460.256059] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 3, lost async page write
[ 1460.256061] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 4, lost async page write
[ 1460.256063] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 5, lost async page write
[ 1460.256065] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 6, lost async page write
[ 1460.256067] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 7, lost async page write
[ 1460.256069] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 8, lost async page write
[ 1460.256071] Buffer I/O error on dev sdd, logical block 9, lost async page write
[ 1460.256118] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 240 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[ 1460.256166] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 1460.256329] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 488 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x104000 phys_seg 60 prio class 0
[ 1460.256445] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 728 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x100000 phys_seg 35 prio class 0
[ 1460.256501] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 868 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 39 prio class 0
[ 1460.256524] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 131072 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 1460.256560] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60435968 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 28 prio class 0
[ 1460.256577] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60436080 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 14 prio class 0
[ 1460.256607] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 60436136 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 20 prio class 0
[ 1460.468038] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[ 1465.840000] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1481.455978] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1481.743976] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 19 using ehci-pci
[ 1487.087969] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1502.703966] usb 1-1.3.2: device descriptor read/64, error -110
[ 1502.812105] usb 1-1.3-port2: attempt power cycle
[ 1503.515969] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 20 using ehci-pci
[ 1514.251972] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 20, error -110
[ 1514.431991] usb 1-1.3.2: new high-speed USB device number 21 using ehci-pci
[ 1525.259962] usb 1-1.3.2: device not accepting address 21, error -110
[ 1525.260154] usb 1-1.3-port2: unable to enumerate USB device

It looks like every time I try to do something with the drive, it goes in shambles and disconnects itself

Your drive definitely failed was this a new drive from a trusted seller or an old drive or a new drive that was incredibly affordable?

@Ramhound It had like 2 or 3 years of age, I can't remember where I bought it though, there are no trusted sellers from where I'm from. The drive was working fine until the day that the power got cut off

The flash storage dirty secret is those USB flash drives are extremely prone to fail, they are definitely, not very resilient
